# SharePoint Hosted App - Creating cascaded drop down on hosted web lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have created a SharePoint Hosted App(Javascript Object Model) that creates lists on the host web.

I need to put some javascript into new and edit forms, a Content Editor, in order to create the cascaded drop down effect on 2 lookup fields. Creating the lists and fields manipulation are made with a press of a button.

Here is the link for the cascaded drop down library:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Here is how I create the lists and the fields for it:

```
// Create a new list on host web
    var createList = function (listTitle, onSuccess, onFieldsReady) {
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title(listTitle);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);

    var lists = hostWeb.get_lists();
    var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);

    currentContext.load(newList);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess(newList, onFieldsReady), onListCreationFail);
}

    // Create a new field on a list
    var createField = function (list, fieldType, fieldName, fieldDisplayName, fieldRequired, onSuccess) {
    var fields = list.get_fields();
    var fieldXml = "<Field Type='" + fieldType + "' Required='" + fieldRequired + "' DisplayName='" + fieldDisplayName + "' Name='" + fieldName + "'></Field>";
    var createdField = fields.addFieldAsXml(fieldXml, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addFieldInternalNameHint | SP.AddFieldOptions.addFieldToDefaultView);

    currentContext.load(createdField);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onProvisionFieldFail);
}
```

Can you please give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

For Office 365 and SharePoint 2013, I advise you to see this blog and video:

> blog:
>   http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/
>
> Video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B8rV56-y1s

For good reason, without using a library of third parties as "SPServices". It will take a while until you get to practice the REST API, but it's incredible work it.

Bit code and a lot of solution. :)

Hope this help.

Thanks.